# C# How to create a Singleton that publishes events & Classes that subscribe?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

**Goal:** Have a singleton publish events and allow any class to subscribe/listen to those events

**Problem:** I cannot figure out how to do this. The code below is illegal but it purveys what I'm trying to do

**TransmitManager Class - Publisher**

```
    //Singleton
    public sealed class TransmitManager
    {

        delegate void TransmitManagerEventHandler(object sender);
        public static event TransmitManagerEventHandler OnTrafficSendingActive;
        public static event TransmitManagerEventHandler OnTrafficSendingInactive;

        private static TransmitManager instance = new TransmitManager();



        //Singleton
        private TransmitManager()
        {

        }

        public static TransmitManager getInstance()
        {
            return instance;
        }

        public void Send()
        {
           //Invoke Event
           if (OnTrafficSendingActive != null)
              OnTrafficSendingActive(this);

          //Code connects & sends data

          //Invoke idle event
          if (OnTrafficSendingInactive != null)
            OnTrafficSendingInactive(this);

       }
   }
```

**Test Class - Event Subscriber**

```
   public class Test
   {

     TrasnmitManager tm = TransmitManager.getInstance();

     public Test()
     {
        //I can't do this below. What should my access level be to able to do this??

        tm.OnTrafficSendingActive += new TransmitManagerEventHandler(sendActiveMethod);

     }

     public void sendActiveMethod(object sender)
     {

        //do stuff to notify Test class a "send" event happend
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make the events `static`.

```
public event TransmitManagerEventHandler OnTrafficSendingActive;
public event TransmitManagerEventHandler OnTrafficSendingInactive;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your events have to be instance members or you have to address them as static.

```
TransmitManager.OnTrafficSendingActive +=...
```

OR

```
public event TransmitManagerEventHandler OnTrafficSendingActive;

...

TransmitManager.Instance.OnTrafficSendingActive+=...
```

Also: use EventHandler as your event delegate. Consider making a custom arguments class and pass the status to just one event instead of multiple events. This will let you pass status messages as well.